# Allow Galaxy SmartTag relaying

Tags: samsung

I have a SmartTag which is paired with **my** device. When my wife goes hiking alone, she wants to take the SmartTag with her so that I can locate her in case of an emergency. Unfortunately, **her** device (a Samsung Galaxy S10) does not seem to relay the Smart Tag position.

What do we need to enable on her phone so that it participates in the "Samsung Galaxy network" that relays SmartTag locations?

Note that we (a) do not want to enable Find My Phone on her phone (she does not like to be tracked *in general*) and (b) we do not want to pair the SmartTag with her phone instead of mine (that would defeat the purpose stated above).

Comment: Instead of using a tag, your wife can share her location through Google Maps (other map and/or chat services might offer similar functionality) for a set amount of time. For example, when she leaves the house she can start sharing her location with you for the next 4 hours. https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7326816

Comment: @NeatNit: Thanks, that's a good idea. We'll try that next time.

Comment: @NeatNit: Works perfectly, thanks for the hint! I'll leave the question open nevertheless, because I think it's an interesting question in its own right.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that! And I agree, the original question is interesting. Can you try to download and set up the Smart Things app on her phone (either from Galaxy Store or Play Store)? I think that's the app that should handle smart tags, but I'm not sure.